# Fixing "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'close'" when multithreading from file?

Tags: python, multithreading, beautifulsoup, urllib2, python-multiprocessing

Getting a AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'close'

Tried closing file (still in code below), recoded twice.

```py
import urllib2
import csv
import lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool  # This is a thread-based Pool
from multiprocessing import cpu_count
placeHolder = []

def crawlToCSV(URLrecord):
    try:
        OpenSomeSiteURL = urllib2.urlopen(URLrecord).read()
        Soup_SomeSite = BeautifulSoup(OpenSomeSiteURL, "lxml")
        OpenSomeSiteURL.close()
        tbodyTags = Soup_SomeSite.find("title")
    except urllib2.URLError:
        print (URLrecord.rstrip() + " -- Error")
        Soup_SomeSite = ""
        OpenSomeSiteURL = ""


if __name__ == "__main__":
    fileName = raw_input()
    pool = Pool(cpu_count() * 2)  # Creates a Pool with cpu_count * 2 threads.
    with open(fileName, "rb") as f:
        results = pool.map(crawlToCSV, f) # results is a list of all the placeHolder lists returned from each call to crawlToCSV
        f.close()
```

Also sorry for my bad coding, first time with Python multithreading, did a lot of mistakes.

Right now trying to get it to run, without erroring out while accepting URLS.

```
  File "test.py", line 26, in <module>
    results = pool.map(crawlToCSV, f) # results is a list of all the placeHolder lists returned from each call to crawlToCSV
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 253, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 572, in get
    raise self._value
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'close'
```

Comment: You don't need to call `close()` yourself when you use `with`, it automatically closes the file when it's done.

Comment: `crawlToCSV` needs to return a value, e.g. `return tbodyTags`.

Comment: Ah, but even without that line of code, it was still erroring out with the same attr error.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'll try that out real quick and get back to ya.

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error.

Comment: Yea, seems to still be handing me the same error.

Comment: Put it in the question so you can format it readably.

Comment: Alright added. -

Comment: if you remove that line I don't see how you could get the exact same error message

Comment: Yea, it's really odd, same error message. Not sure why it's happening.

Answer (score 1):

If you use with, it will close automatically once whatever actions are completed.

```
with open(fileName, "rb") as f:
```

Maybe the file is being read incorrectly. `rb` is for a binary file. Try this instead.

```
with open(fileName, "r") as f:
```

If you would like to manually close, this is how to do it. `with` is a better solution though.

```
f = open("filename")
    ...# Actions to perform on file
f.close()
```